# Getting install package leads to PyCrypto error while installing Python libraries?

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to install smartapi Python library

```
pip install smartapi
```

But it's throw error.....

```
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  error: legacy-install-failure

 × Encountered error while trying to install package.
 ╰─> PyCrypto

 note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
 hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

error image:
[image: error image]

My **Python version is 3.10.2** and my **pip version is 22.0.3**

Comment: Well, as the error tells you, there's a problem with the package. Most likely the package authors are the ones to fix it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [can't install pycrypto, python 3.10, how to fix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69516513/cant-install-pycrypto-python-3-10-how-to-fix)

Answer (score 0):

[PyCrypto is no longer supported](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bpip%5d%20PyCrypto). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/69516560/7976758 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/58077358/7976758 .

SmartAPI [requires](https://pypi.org/project/SmartAPI/) Python 2 (see the bottom of the left column). Try Python 2.7. Or find out a different package.